# How can I implement a custom challenge handler in Xamarin for iOS using IBM MobileFirst?

Tags: ios, xamarin, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to implement an adapter-based authentication using IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation 6.3 and Xamarin in iOS.

I have followed the IBM documentation on how to setup a customSecurityTest, adding realms and equivalent loginModules within authenticationConfig.xml. I have then setup 2 adapter procedures:

- `authenticateUser` with `securityTest="wl_unprotected"`, and another
- `HelloFromServer` with a `securityTest="SingleStepAuthAdapter"` that actually does a user authentication, and executing `WL.Server.setActiveUser("SingleStepAuthRealm", userIdentity)` to create the user identity.

I have then created an iOS app using Xamarin Studio. Tried to invoke `HelloFromServer`, which as expected runs my ChallengeHandler module BUT within the `HandleChallenge` method while trying to invoke the `authenticateUser` procedure on the server, it respond back with another `authRequired=TRUE`.

Anybody having the same problem?

Comment: This is where you need to actually provide your implementation of the both the adapter procedure and client code that handles it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You did not provide any useful implementation code that can be inspected for errors - add both the adapter authentication implementation as well as the client-side code of the challenge handler.
2. While I have no experience with Xamarin, it should be noted that in order to get started you could:

   - Use the same *exact* implementation as done in the [Adapter-based authentication](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/) tutorial. That is, the implementation in the adapter files, project configuration and so on.
   - Follow through the native iOS implementation, also [based on the tutorial](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-native-ios-applications/)

The MFP Studio project and the native iOS project [can be downloaded from here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/authentication-security/adapter-based-authentication/adapter-based-authentication-native-ios-applications/).

Comment: Sorry still trying to learn how to post code within this "Add Comment" window.

Answer (score 0):

If you are repeatedly getting back `authRequired=true`, it looks like you are not notifying the server of the success from your `HandleChallenge` function. You can refer to the `CustomChallengeHandler.cs` provided with the sample that is shipped with the component. This is coded to handle a form-based challenge. You can modify it to handle an realm for adapter-based authentication.

So, here are the changes you need to do

1)  You should implement the `GetAdapterAuthenticationParameters` method in your ChallengeHandler class.

For example,

```
public AdapterAuthenticationInfo AdapterAuthenticationParameters = new AdapterAuthenticationInfo();

....
public override AdapterAuthenticationInfo GetAdapterAuthenticationParameters ()
{
    return AdapterAuthenticationParameters; 
}
```

2) In the `HandleChallenge` function of your ChallengeHandler class, set the `isAuthRequired = true`. For example,

```
if (challenge.ResponseJSON["authRequired"] == true)
{
    WorklightProcedureInvocationData invocationData = new WorklightProcedureInvocationData("DemoAdapter", 
                                "submitAuthentication" , new object[1]); // Add the parameters you want to pass to the adapter
    AdapterAuthenticationParameters.InvocationData = invocationData;
    AdapterAuthenticationParameters.RequestOptions = null;
    isAdapterAuth = true; 
}
else
{
    isAdapterAuth = false;
    authSuccess = true;
 }
```

Comment: Tried this but getting an error "Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds". I'm getting this error when I return TRUE on ShouldSubmitAdapterAuthentication () which I believe triggers GetAdapterAuthenticationParameters ().

Comment: Are you building upon the WorklightSample that ships with the component ? If yes, please provide the CustomChallengeHandler implementation and the adapter's implementation files. Otherwise, it would be helpful if you can provide the entire Xamarin project you're using

Comment: The "Destination array was not long enough" error appears to be due to a bug in the Xamarin component code. We'll issue a patch soon.